# simple_html_dom parser : filter found tag

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I would like to parse code with structure like this :

```
<p class=class1>
 <i>.</i>
 <b>..</b>
<a class=class2></a>
</p>
```

and i need to get whole content of `<p>` but only without `<a>` tags with. I need to keep there all the other tags like `<i>` or `<b>`
How can i do it?

Now i have just this code :

```
 $content = $page->find('p[class=class1]');
 foreach($content as $text)
  {
    $inner=$text->innertext();
  }
```

it´s able to find whole content with `<a>` tags. And

Comment: have u managed to grab the content and have a variable containing said content? show what u have so far at least (php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could loop the child nodes and check the `nodeName()`. If that is an `a`, you could set the `outertext` to an empty string:

Try it like this:

```
$data = <<<DATA
<p class=class1>
 content
 <div>test</div>
 <i>.</i>
 <b>..</b>
<a class=class2></a>
</p>
DATA;
$html = str_get_html($data);

foreach($html->find('p.class1') as $element) {
    foreach ($element->children as $child) {
        if ($child->nodeName() === "a") {
            $child->outertext = '';
        }
    }
}

echo $html->save();
```

That would give you:

`<p class=class1>  content  <div>test</div>  <i>.</i>  <b>..</b>  </p>`

Or if you want to remove all (nested) anchors:

```
foreach ($html->find('p.class1 a') as $element) {
    $element->outertext = '';
}
```

Comment: There is problem, that there are more tag´s inside <p>, like <b>, or <i> which i would like to keep it the variable to show them at my webside.... I forgot to said it at first time, sorry

Comment: Then you could update your question with the accurate example data.